# convert date with time into hour AM/PM format

Tags: reactjs, antd, timepicker

Want to covert Thu Apr 28 2022 07:00:00 GMT+0530 into 7pm
UI is like this,

[image]

also want to covert that 7pm to Thu Apr 28 2022 07:00:00 format

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/creating/
This may help you to set the format for your time. Please follow the docs.

Comment: @NoumanRafique https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/  Momentjs is deprecated and they suggest alternatives

Comment: By default, Antd Timepicker use moment to handle the time. Antd team haven't announce anything related to momentjs. Alternatively, we can create own timepicker that uses library other than momentjs like dayjs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if it is working for you

```
    var time = new Date('Thu Apr 28 2022 19:00:00 GMT+0530');
    console.log(
        time.toLocaleString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', hour12: true })
    );
```

Comment: i get it with date also want time only

Answer (score 0):

You can format your date like this:

```
<TimePicker
    showMinute={false}
    showSecond={false}
    use12Hours
    onChange={(val, data) => {
        // Thu Apr 28 2022 07:00:00 format
        console.log(val?.format('ddd, MMMM D YYYY, h:mm:ss'));
    }}
/>
```

You can read more about formatting in moment documentation. [Moment Format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)